# Combine values of different XML elements into one with separator usig XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML looking like something like that (The real XML is much more complicated, I have simplified it to show the actual problem):

```
<record>
    <abstract>this is abstract information</abstract>
    <author>Vardenis Pavardenis</autor>
    <author>Steeve Jobs</autor> 
</record>
```

I need to combine abstract and author information into one node and separate them by `&#xa;` so the result would be look like:

```
<record>
    <description>this is abstract information`&#xa;`Author: Vardenis Pavardenis`&#xa;`Author: Steeve Jobs</description> 
</record>
```

The problem is, what the number of author and abstract nodes is unknown and there might be no author or no description nodes at all. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:for-each>` to loop through all child elements of `<description>` regardless of how many are there, and combine the values like so :

```
<xsl:template match="record">
  <record>
      <description>
          <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:if test="self::author">Author : </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">&#xa;</xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </description>
  </record>
</xsl:template>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform demo`](http://xsltransform.net/bdxtr8)</kbd>**